# Despliegue Proyecto Laravel en Apache

Tags: laravel, apache2, deployment

Estoy desplegando un proyecto de Laravel en Apache, pero en vez de ver la pantalla de Inicio, veo el archivo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el virtual host:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer para que se vea la aplicación web?

Comment: Esto significa que ese Apache HTTP no tiene el módulo PHP habilitado

Comment: Cómo se habilita? He probado a cambiar de php.ini cgi.fix_pathinfo=0, que estaba en 1, pero se ve igual